# Add checkmark image to same row as the was selected UITableView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have a problem and I hope one of you can suggest a better way of accomplishing what I am trying to do.

So I have a UITableView with a list of items. Each tableview row has an "Add" button. When the add button is pushed, the selected item is added to master list. (Think of a to-do app),  That works fine, no problems there. What I want is some type of notification that the item was added to the list.  Such as a checkmark that appears on the same row that was added for two seconds then disappears. Here is my code:

```
-(void)addToList:(id)sender event:(id)event{

//This is the add button method on each cell.

NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.theTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.theTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];

//Check image is the image of the checkmark that I want to display when the user adds an item.

checkImage.alpha = 0.0f;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7f];

checkImage.alpha = 1.0f;

checkImage.frame = CGRectMake(currentTouchPosition.x + 100, currentTouchPosition.y, 25, 25);

[UIView commitAnimations];

....[only relevant code shown]...

}
```

When the user taps the add button, the checkImage fades in and positions it self where the user touched the row + 100 pixels to the right. That works fine, but it does not position the checkmark in the center of the row, it could be in the center, near the top or near the bottom, depending on where the user tapped the add button.  I need it in the center, or a different way to go about this. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: How do you add `checkImage` to the table view?

Comment: checkImage is just a regular UIImageView, it just sits on top of the view, it is not added to the tableview specifically.

Comment: What happens when user scrolls? Won't you lose your position this way?

Comment: Yes, your right. I have to figure something else out. :)

Comment: I've added code that should take care of it. You will also have to make changes to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as mentioned at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the `indexPath`, get the cell using,

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [self.theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGSize cellSize = cell.contentView.frame.size;
```

and later,

```
CGPoint touchPositionInCell = [self.theTableView convertPoint:currentTouchLocation toView:cell.contentView];

CGPoint checkmarkCenter = CGPointMake(touchPositionInCell.x + 100, cellSize.height/2);
CGRect checkmarkFrame = CGRectZero;
checkmarkFrame.origin = checkmarkCenter;
checkmarkFrame = CGRectInset(checkmarkFrame, -12, -12);

checkImage.frame = checkmarkFrame;

[cell.contentView addSubview:checkImage];
```

This should position the checkmark in the vertical center.

And I hope you are aware of concept of reusable cells. Try to remember the `indexPath` of the cell the `checkImage` is in. If you see a request for a cell at that indexPath then add `checkImage` as its subview.

Comment: Brilliant. Looks like I have some learning to do! Perfect solution. Thanks so much Deepak, your a legend.

Comment: that was a great one, but I am having a issue, I am trying to add image to selected rows depends upon a condition, but having the issue. I have posted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194934/how-to-load-images-to-seletcted-rows-in-a-uitableview/8195751#8195751 please share any idea.