# How to load images to seletcted rows in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview

I am trying to load image into a tableview row. The scenario is, i have two arrays say

```
nameID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"01",@"02",@"05",@"06",@"07",@"08",@"09",nil];
```

and

```
testID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"02",@"05",@"07",@"09",nil];
```

and I loaded the `nameID` values to the tableview. Now I need to load images to the row, if the `indexPath.row` value contains in `testID`. I tried to load, at first time it is working but when I scroll, the image is loading to all rows as I scroll. So, how can I implement that in a proper way?
Here is my code:

```
NSString *temp1 = [friendsID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([alertArray containsObject:temp1]) {
    tickImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tickImg];
}
```

Please share your thoughts.
Thanks.

Comment: Please include the code from your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: I have added the code i got the image loaded at first time, but as I scroll it is loading to other rows too. How can I control that?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this snippet will help you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    //configure cell
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",indexPath.row]; //convert row number to string with format ##
    if ([testId containsObject:imageName]) {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        cell.imageView.image = img;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [nameId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i got the image on the selected rows, but the problems is when  I scroll, the image is adding to other rows as I scroll. How can I stop that?

Comment: and actually the values in the array is not as i mentioned in the question. It may vary.

Comment: @John On the top, it looks like a cell reuse issue. You should nil the `imageView`'s `image` when `testId` doesn't contain the image i.e. add an `else` clause where you do `cell.imageView.image = nil;`

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have posted the same here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222566/uitableview-repeating-image-when-scroll and i got a reply, that is working fine but at the first time table appear the image is not loaded.